# Printenv list all environment variable from the command line but failed to list all environment variable from code

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

The below code does not list all environment variables like it does from command line, if I execute printenv > ~/Desktop/test.txt from the command line. I tried using pipe/popen also but the result is same.
e.g. printenv list down the environment variable ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY in terminal but from code it returns null.
std::genenv(ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY) returns null.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("printenv > ~/Desktop/test.txt");
}
```

Comment: Note that `system` creates a separate and distinct process which runs a shell to execute the command, You don't print the environment of your own program, but that of the shell in the child-process.

Comment: So how can I get all environment variable and it's values list in the code

Comment: @shrabanakumar Each process has its own separate environment (and thus its own list of environment variables). When a process is created, it inherits a copy of the parent process's environment, but after that it's on its own. `printenv` is printing *its* environment, which it inherited from your program, which may or may not have any connection at all to what your shells usually have.

Comment: I have tried using std::genenv(ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY) it returns null. But in command line printenv list down the environment variable ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY but from code it returns null

Comment: Please create a simple test program like `#include <cstdlib> int main() { char* e = std::getenv("ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY"); if (env == nullptr) { std::cout << "ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY doesn't exist\n"; } else { std::cout << "ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY is " << env << '\n'; } }` (add newlines as and when needed). Then build it and run it in a shell. Directly afterward (and in the same shell!) run the command `echo $ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY`. Copy-paste the output of both commands (preferably the full terminal text, including prompts and commands) into your question.

Comment: Where is the `ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY` environment variable set? If it's not set in your program's process, or in a parent process (before your program is started), it won't exist in your program's process.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `system` creates a child process so the environment variables might be different from the ones existing in your application's environment.

You can use `std::genenv` to get environment variables.

Comment: I have tried using std::genenv(ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY) it returns null. But in command line printenv list down the environment variable ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY but from code it returns null